# Normal Approximation - how many bookings so probability for "overbooking" stays under certain value

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation, central-limit-theorem

I need some help with the following:

A hotel has $r$ rooms. The probability that a guest who booked a room also appears (which means: no cancellation) is $p = 0.9$.

I'd like to know how many rooms can be booked so that the probability for "no guest has to leave (due to overbooking)" stays under the value $a$.

- Let $S_n ~ Bin(n,p)$ the number of guests, who actually booked a room AND did appear.
- $P(S_n > r) = P(\frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{npq}} > \frac{r-np}{\sqrt{npq}}) = 1 - P(S_n'' \leq \frac{r-np}{\sqrt{npq}}) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{r-np}{\sqrt{npq}})$.
- This value needs to be $< a$. So:
- $\frac{r-np}{\sqrt{npq}} \ge z_{1-a}$ where $z_{1-a}$ is the inverse of standard normal distribution $\phi$.
- This leads to: $r-np \ge z_{1-a}\cdot \sqrt{npq} \Leftrightarrow \frac{r}{p}-n \ge z_{1-a} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{nq}{p}}$, finally:
- $(\sqrt{n})^2 + z_{1-a} \sqrt{\frac{q}{p}} \sqrt{n} - \frac{r}{\sqrt{p}} \leq 0$.

Now I'd like to find the zero point and then it should be done?! So: How to conclude? And have I done it correct so far?

Comment: you need to apply a continuity correction since you are approximating Binomial with Normal

Comment: You want to keep the probability for "no guest has to leave" _above_ some value, not below.

Comment: But I did use the prob for "more guests than r rooms" needs to be above some value?

Answer (score 1):

$r-np \geq z_{1-a}\cdot \sqrt{npq}$

We can change the inequality to an equality, because we have to square the equation. Squaring is not an equivalent transformation. You can to decide at the end if n has to be $\leq$ or $\geq$.

Taking the square on both sides

$r^2-2rnp+n^2p^2=z^2\cdot npq$

$p^2n^2-(2rp+z^2\cdot p\cdot q)n+r^2=0$

Using the quadratic formula we have

$n_{1/2}=\frac{2rp+z^2\cdot p\cdot q\pm\sqrt{(2rp+z^2\cdot p\cdot q)^2-4\cdot p^2\cdot r^2}}{2p^2}$

$n_{1/2}=\frac{2rp+z^2\cdot p\cdot q\pm\sqrt{4p^2r^2+4rz^2qp^2+z^4q^2p^2-4\cdot p^2\cdot r^2}}{2p^2}$

$n_{1/2}=\frac{2rp+z^2\cdot p\cdot q\pm\sqrt{4rz^2qp^2+z^4q^2p^2}}{2p^2}$

You can check with the inequality at the beginning which value for $n$ is right.

We can drop the continuity correction factor if $n$ is sufficiently large enough. In the most cases it will be true. One thumb of rule is $n \cdot p \cdot q\geq 9$.

[Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2*50*0.9%2B1.96%5E2*%200.9*%200.1%2Bsqrt%7B4*50*1.96%5E2*0.1*0.9%5E2%2B1.96%5E4*0.1%5E2*0.9%5E2%7D)%2F(2*0.9%5E2)) to the calculation using the formula

[Calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D0)%5E50%20(61%20choose%20k)*0.9%5Ek*0.1%5E(61-k)) using the binomial distribution with $n=61,p=0.9$ and $x=50$

[Calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D0)%5E50%20(60%20choose%20k)*0.9%5Ek*0.1%5E(60-k)) using the binomial distribution with $n=60,p=0.9$ and $x=50$

Comment: Thank you so far. For $p=0.9, r=50, a=0.05, q=0.1$ I get $n_1 \approx 57.86414$ and $n_2 \approx 53.33907$. Comparing with the inequality, neither $n_1$ nor $n_2$ solves it?

Comment: I got $n_1\leq 50.9846$ and $n_2\geq 60.6433$ see the link at my answer.  It is obvious that the final result is $n=61$ But also with this result the first equation does not hold for $n=60.6433$. It holds only for the squared equation. But the cummulative probabilities are $Bin(60,0.9.50)=7.3\%$ and $Bin(61,0.9.50)=3.81\%$. Thus $n=61$ is the right result.

Comment: I add the link to the answer.

Comment: Something of what I've done must be incorrect - the solution should be "52" (it was given). Now I'm confused :o

Comment: If I set $1-\phi (\frac{r-np}{\sqrt{npq}}) < 0.05$ and look at the inverse of phi, I get $\phi(1.644854) > 0.95$. Solving $\frac{r-np}{\sqrt{npq}} = 1.644854$ brings $n = 51.6164$ ?

Comment: $n$ is not large enough. You have to use the continuity correction factor. In this case the formula of my answer has to be adjusted.

Comment: For the approximation we have additional the  rule of thumb $n\cdot p \cdot q>9$. This is not the case. Therefore it is no wonder that is not working very well. For $p=0.9$ $n$ should be larger than round about $100$.